# How to support the columns of a second level of an hypaethral building with reduction in space by height?

Tags: structures, modeling, building-design, safety, columns

[image]

In this multi-leveled [hypaethral](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypaethral) building model there is a problem that the columns of the second floor aren't directly situated on the columns of the first floor.

How to support the columns of the second floor while preserving the reduction in floor vicinity apparent in this model (the third floor is smaller than the second and the second floor is smaller than the first floor)?

One way would be to just make the columns of the first floor wider, but then they may cover too much space and will not appear "gentle".

This model is from the computer game *Age of Empires 2: Definitive Edition, Return of Rome*.

Comment: You have to transfer stresses to the lower columns. That means through that floor. Notice how a dome is smaller as you go up but beautifully transmits compressive loads down to the ground. Basics of ARCHitecture.

Comment: I am not a buildings architect, just curious :)

Comment: @Abel someone posted here a commercial spam post. I as a non registered user can't delete it or even flag it for some odd reason.

Comment: By the way, should this question be migrated to Graphic Design Stack Exchange?

Comment: @somo should you have posted on the Graphic Design Stack originally?

Comment: @SolarMike no, I haven't post it there at all. Should it be migrated to there?

Comment: Aren't there 2 rows of columns in the base floor (like "períptero" [here](https://www.pngegg.com/en/png-peskl))? The second row would be invisible in isometry and it would make sense for the upper floor, where each of the columns would stand in the middle of 4 base floor columns. This seems like feasible design when you use arched ceiling for the base floor.

Answer (score 0):

The thickened slab acts as a continuous beam around the perimeter to carry the columns and weight above. The slab needs to be thick and heavy enough to resist the eccentrical punching shear and overcome the bending stress in the beam-column joint.

[image]

OpenOffice Drawing Template:

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: What is your blue slab made from? This could work with modern materials, e.g. reinforced concrete or steel beams, but I'm not sure it would work with 'traditional' materials, which is what I *thought* OP was asking with regard to?

Comment: @JonathanRSwift correct, I meant to natural materials.

Comment: Portland cement is significantly weaker, especially in tension, compared to most carved solid stone used in building... Trick to building with carved stone is to make sure all the joints between the stones are in compression due to the weight of materials.

Comment: I am not an Architect nor an archaeologist, so I couldn't pinpoint the slab material. But it is worth noting that that cautious material, similar to Roman concrete, with steel/wood reinforcement had been developed and used in the SE Asia region for a very long time.

Comment: Hello @r13. Please tell me, what is the program with which you created this model? Thanks !!!

Comment: Use the "drawing" template in "OpenOffice".

Comment: Wasn't "OpenOffice" deprecated? I have "LibreOffice Draw" on my computer. I should probably look for some tutorial about how to create anything with this.

Comment: Its drawing template is quite versatile. Try it yourself.

Comment: @r13 when I go to File > New > Drawing I get a blank page. Not even background squares with Grey borders are on. Anyway I am by no means a graphic designer, just a humble scripter. I don't even what are the main uses of this program. I might consult a building architect.

Comment: Sorry for your trouble, for which I've no clue what had happened. Please keep in mind it is free to try and free to discard.